# clash of clans on ipod gen 4 transferring to samsung s3

Tags: clash-of-clans

Hi I have been playing clash of clans on ipod gen 4 however i cannot access it now on my ipod. I have a samsung s3. i have downloaded clash onto my s3 and want to continue with my existing village etc on my s3. please please can someone tell me how to do this. need idiots guide to do but many thanks if someone can help. clan now has no leader playing ;-(

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete Clash of Clans from your Samsung Galaxy S3.
2. Create a new Google account and delete the old one from your device
   under Settings > Accounts.
3. Set the Google account as your primary at Google Play or just
   download Clash of Clans and it will ask you to select one of your
   two accounts to download, select the new one.
4. Complete the tutorial and get a linking code from your iPod 4.

More information at this Wikia page if you still don't understand it:
http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Device_Linking_Guide